# Calcular porcentaje de un salario para definir el bono

Tags: c#, consola

Debo calcular el bono de un usuario de acuerdo a su salario. El salario lo debe ingresar y de acuerdo al monto ingresado se calcula el bono, el cual debe estar dentro de uno de estos rangos:

> `salario >= 100` y `salario <= 200` porcentaje 10%
>
> `salario > 200` y `salario <= 300` porcentaje 20%
>
> `salario > 300` porcentaje 30%

Este el codigo que tengo:

```
  Console.WriteLine("Ingrese su salario:");      
     var tarifa = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        double salario;
        double porcentaje;
        double bono;
        if (salario >=100 && salario <=200)
        {
            salario * porcentaje(10%)= bono;
        }
        if (salario >200 && salario <= 300)
        {
            salario* porcentaje(20%)=bono; 
        }
        if (salario >300)
        {
            salario* porcentaje(30%) = bono;
        }
        else
        else 
   
        Console.WriteLine("Salario : " + salario);
        Console.WriteLine("Porcentaje: " + porcentaje);
        Console.WriteLine("Bono:" + bono);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Gracias por incluir tu código, pero ahora explícanos ¿cual es tu problema específico? ¿Qué te tiene trancada? Por ejemplo, yo veo que tu código seguramente no compila, pero no has dicho nada al respecto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La lógica de programación me parece que está bien, solo hay que hacer unos pequeños ajustes a tu código:

```
Console.WriteLine("Ingrese su salario:");
decimal salario = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
decimal bono = 0;
int porcentaje = 0;

if (salario >= 100 && salario <= 200)
{
    bono = salario * (decimal).10;
    porcentaje = 10;
}
else if (salario > 200 && salario <= 300)
{
    bono = salario * (decimal).20;
    porcentaje = 20;
}
else if (salario > 300)
{
    bono = salario * (decimal).30;
    porcentaje = 30;
}

Console.WriteLine("Salario : " + salario);
Console.WriteLine("Porcentaje: " + porcentaje + "%");
Console.WriteLine("Bono:" + bono);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Recuerda que al hacer las asignaciones antes del `=` es la variable donde se alojará tu resultado, por ejemplo para este caso, no es posible hacer esto `salario* porcentaje(20%)=bono;`, debe quedar algo como `bono = salario * (decimal).20;`.

Comment: aun no lo compilo por que tengo errores

Comment: donde te da error?